# no match for call to ‘(const Y) (int&, std::mersenne_twister_engine<long unsigned int,

Tags: c++

there is my .hpp :

```
#include <random>
#include <ctime>
#include <cmath>

#ifndef RECUIT_HPP
#define RECUIT_HPP




template < class E, class Func, class TempSeq, class RandomY, class RNG>
E recuit_simule(const Func & phi, E x0, const TempSeq & T, const RandomY & Y, RNG & G, long unsigned N) {
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> U(0,1);
    E y;
    double u;
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        y=Y(x0, G);
        u=U(G);
        if(u <= fmin(1, exp((phi(x0) - phi(y))/T(N)))) {
            x0=y;
        }
    }
    return x0;
}

#endif
```

and my .cpp :

```
#include "recuit.hpp"
#include <iostream>

class Y {
    private:
        std::normal_distribution<double> N;
    public:
        Y() : N(0,1) {}
        double operator()(const double & x, std::mt19937 & G) { return x + N(G); }
};


int main() {
    auto phi=[](const double & x) { return x*x*x*x*x*x - 48*x*x; };
    auto T=[] (long unsigned n) { return 10 * pow(0.9, n); };
    Y A;
    std::mt19937 G;
    double x = recuit_simule(phi, 0, T, A, G, 1000);
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When i compile my .cpp, I have the following error in my .hpp :

> recuit.hpp:17:6: error: no match for call to ‘(const Y) (int&,
>   std::mersenne_twister_engine&)’

for the line :

```
    y=Y(x0, G);
```

And I don't understand why

Comment: you can help yourself and us here by creating a [MRE]. Yes your code is reproducible and not large honestly, but there is still a lot of code that is irrelevant to your current error. Example this is how I stripped down your code until I reached a propper [MRE]: https://godbolt.org/z/rNGKdc This helps a lot in identifying the issue.

Answer (score 2):

`Y::operator()` is not `const` so you cannot call it on a const object. So make the parameter `Y` mutable:

```
E recuit_simule(const Func & phi, E x0, const TempSeq & T, RandomY & Y, RNG & G, long unsigned N) {
//                                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~
//                                                         not const
```

---

Side note: your code is very confusion and difficult to read because you don't use a different notation for types and variables. E.g. `Y` is a type but also the name of a parameter. And you are not consistent: sometimes variables are on lowercase, sometimes are capitalized.

Comment: Thank you for your help and your advice !